# S3 GetObjectTagging error for only subset of similar files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a spark application that creates 1000 files in S3 bucket. Later I need to move these files to a different directory in the same S3 bucket. But when I try this using AWSCLI, a very few files (~10) are not moved and show the error of AccessDenied as follows:

```
[padmanabhpande]$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/datasets_tmp s3://my-bucket-name/datasets-2020-06-22 --recursive

copy failed: s3://my-bucket-name/datasets_tmp/train-2020-06-22/id=138751/part-00020-6f77e24e-4df8-4ef5-9743-1d7a84deba40.c000.snappy.parquet to s3://my-bucket-name/datasets-2020-06-22/train-2020-06-22/id=138751/part-00020-6f77e24e-4df8-4ef5-9743-1d7a84deba40.c000.snappy.parquet An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied
```

Why this is happening for only 10s of files and rest 990 are moved successfully, when the same spark application creates all these files at the same time.

Comment: Are you owner of these 10s of files? This could explain why you have no access to them.

Comment: spark application is running in another AWS account, but files are created with sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl"). Besides, this error happens only for a small subset of files. And aws s3 mv is executed by the same AWS account which creates these files.

Comment: I would look at few of the files that don't work and compare them with those that work. Maybe they have some specific ACL permission setup, different owners, or there is bucket policy blocking them. Could be many reasons.